# AddEventListener in Parent and postMessage in iframe doesn't work together

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, stripe-payments, postmessage

I'm trying to follow [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure-iframe#handle-redirect), while developing one feature, but I've encounter a problem with a communication between **a webpage and an iframe**.

#### index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  parent<br>
  <iframe src="./sca-iframe.html" width="100" height="100" ></iframe>
</body>
<script>
  debugger
  function on3DSComplete() {
    debugger
    console.log("Event received!!!!")
  }
  window.addEventListener('3DS-authentication-complete', on3DSComplete, false);
</script>
</html>
```

#### iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  iframe
  <script>
    debugger
    window.top.postMessage('3DS-authentication-complete');
    console.log("postMessage('3DS-authentication-complete')")
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Where is a problem? I cannot find it :(

Plunkr:

http://embed.plnkr.co/0CLhHnncF4Ntsif0u9zY/
http://run.plnkr.co/preview/cjzi23ugh0005315uxn7fj6od/

Github example repo:

https://github.com/noisy/strie-customize-the-3d-secure-ui-test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing that will fire a `3DS-authentication-complete` event here.

What you want is to listen to the [`message` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent). However since this event may be fired by multiple sources, you'd be better check the integrity of th message content.

So you'll end up with something like:

```
function on3DSComplete() {
  console.log("Event received!!!!")
}
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  if(event.origin === location.origin &&
    event.data === "3DS-authentication-complete") {
    on3DSComplete();
  }
});
```

```js
function on3DSComplete() {
  console.log("Event received!!!!")
}

function waitFor3DSMessage(event) {
  if(event.data === "3DS-authentication-complete") {
    on3DSComplete();
    // in case we don't need to listen anymore
    window.removeEventListener('message', waitFor3DSMessage);
  }
}
window.addEventListener('message', waitFor3DSMessage);

const framecontent = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  iframe
  <script>  
    // in StackSnippet we need to use 'parent', because 'top' is the actual Q/A page
    parent.postMessage('3DS-authentication-complete', '*');
  <\/script>
</body>
</html>`;
document.getElementById('frame').src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([framecontent], {type: 'text/html'}));
```

```html
parent
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.parent.postMessage('3DS-authentication-complete', '*');` instead maybe when posting the message ?